# How to print several triangles in one line (HASKELL)

Tags: haskell, recursion, triangle

I have this self-defined `IO() Triangle`, which has each row of a triangle as an element in a list:

```
import Data.List ( intersperse )
type Triangle = Char -> Int -> [String]

centeredTriangle :: Triangle
centeredTriangle c n = [replicate (n-i) ' ' ++ intersperse ' ' (replicate i c) | i <- [0 .. n]]
```

Output:

```
Ok, one module loaded.
ghci> centeredTriangle '*' 6
["      ","     *","    * *","   * * *","  * * * *"," * * * * *","* * * * * *"]
```

When I run my main function, I use `unlines` to print out the triangle like so:

```
triangles :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IO()
triangles a b c = do 
    putStr $ unlines $ centeredTriangle '*' a
    putStr $ unlines $ centeredTriangle '*' b 
    putStr $ unlines $ centeredTriangle '*' c
```

Output:

```
ghci> triangles 1 2 3

*

 *
* *

  *
 * *
* * *
```

I want to print the triangles on the same line, like so:

```
ghci> triangles 1 2 3

               *
       *      * *
 *    * *    * * *
```

I realise it may be a bigger task than I first anticipated, but my first thought was to use `centeredTriangle` to get the bottom line (last element of the list) of each triangle, and put them toghether in a new string which I then put as the last element in a new list of strings. I thought If I do this for each element (starting from the last) and up to the top I can print the triangles in the same line using my main funtion. How do I achieve this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "on the same line"? Can you add the exact output you want to your question?

Comment: You will need to add the right amount of vertical and horizontal space to make this work. Maybe, you could start by making a function to add a given amount of padding to a `[String]`, assuming it is "rectangular". Then, pad the triangles so that they have the same size X*Y. Finally, concatenate them horizontally.

Comment: Imagine that we modify `centeredTriangle` so that each line was actually the full length of the triangle's "base".  So, the second line for a 3-triangle would be "  *  " instead of "  *".  That would make it easier to write a function that put two of those figures (still considered as lists of lines) side-by-side. You would only call `unlines` at the very end, after having put all the figures together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `type Triangle = [String]`,

1. Write a function `boundingBox :: Triangle -> (Int,Int)`.
2. Write a function `maxBoundingBox :: [Triangle] -> (Int,Int)`.
3. Write a function `putInBox :: Triangle -> (Int,Int) -> Triangle`.
4. Write a function `makeSameSize :: [Triangle] -> [Triangle]`.
5. Write a function `sideToSide :: Triangle -> [String] -> [String]`.

Use it in `foldr` to conjoin all the resized `Triangle`s together.

Some of the above functions aren't needed if you are the one creating these triangles in the first place. Then you just know the bounding box of the triangle you *would* create from the given parameters.